# limiting scroll issue

Tags: html, css, scroll, limit

Hey, I have a small issue, which I posted here before, but apparently the solution I got only fixed half the problem.  I need to limit the scroll bar, to only appear once the window is resized to a width of 848px, which was resolved with CSS media queries.  My problem now, is that once the scrollbar appears, it enables scrolling to a larger area than I want.  It allows you to scroll right, all the way to the edge of the furthest element.  I want the scrolling to **only** be allowed inside that same 848px.  I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't get it.  Much thanks in advance.

Check out the example at http://brianbattenfeld.com/fingers

Comment: I added the html and css tag, since your previous question seems to have the same tags.

Comment: nice to `want` (im quoting you here)

Comment: The general solution to this is to remove the element that causes the space, and put it outside the element that has the scroll bar.

Comment: @Roflcoptr thanks.  @pekka but the element with the scroll bar is the the window, or "<html>" element.  I can't put the element outside of this.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little confused about what your tying to do but... you could turn off the tell the element to only scroll vertically with CSS.

```
#element{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;    
}
```